# Rewrite or Redirect url htacces

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I´m trying to do something like this, but I can´t get it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)pagina1(.*)$ $1pagina$2 [R=301,L]
```

($2, because I need pass some parameters in the url)

How can I "redirect or rewrite" all files: (pagina1.html, pagina2.html, pagina3.html,etc) to pagina.html

I have to work with relative url, because I want to do for all folders inside a directory.

Well, after 2 days trying, I don´t know how can i do...

Answer (score 0):

With this you could redirect all *.html to pagina.html

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ pagina.html [QSA]
```

Comment: At the end I got it, the suggestion of IKER VAZQUEZ help me think another way, much easier

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/pagina([0-9]+).html http://your-url/folder/subfolder/$1/pagina.html [QSA]

Like I want make this rule for only one directory and all its folders, just put the path up this directory.

Suggestion: Deactive the "error404" htaccess rule, to see the path you got with "$1" and adjust it.